# $ as dollar not as meta character in regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I encountered such a problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':  ['Alice','John','Peter','Richard'],
'salary': ['90000', '1000$', '80000', '900$']
```

})

Some cells are in the national currency & some in dollars. I want to create a new variable to divide the national currency & some in dollars as below

```
df['$'] = 1
df.ix[df['salary'].str.contains("$") == True, '$'  ] =70
```

though i get

```
df['$']
0    70
1    70
2    70
3    70
Name: $, dtype: int64
```

I guess the problem is $ meta character in this case and i need to convert it to string. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), `$` is special character in regex, so need escape by `\`:

```
df['$'] = np.where(df['salary'].str.contains("\$"), 70, 1)
print (df)
      name salary   $
0    Alice  90000   1
1     John  1000$  70
2    Peter  80000   1
3  Richard   900$  70
```

Comment: I've done "df['$'] = np.where(df['salary'].str.contains("\$"), 70, 1)" & get just 70 then df.ix[df['salary'].str.contains("\$") == True, '$'  ] =70 & that's all right!